# A stationary object stuck in an render animation

Tags: rendering, animation

there is nothing in the preview, and when I render the animation, some objects appear

Help me, how to make them disappear

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your outliner, some objects might be disabled for the viewport but not for rendering.